# How to fetch properly Place ID given the name of a city. Trying to reduce cost of billing

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

At this moment we are able to retrieve the city ID given the name of it. But I'm trying to reduce the cost of the billing. And taking a look to the code we are doing like this:

```
var token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
            Places.initialize(context, <API_KEY>)
            var placesClient = Places.createClient(context)

            val request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                .setLocationBias(RectangularBounds.newInstance(UtilsPlaces.generateGlobalWorldBounds()))
                .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.CITIES)
                .setSessionToken(token)
                .setQuery(<CITY_NAME>)
                .build()

            placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener { response ->
                var prediction = response.autocompletePredictions[0]
                placeAddress.placeId = prediction.placeId

               <Do stuff with the place id retrieved>
            }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    <Do stuff in case of failure>
                }
```

So my question is.. is the good way to retrieve the id? Or exist  a better way?

I saw we can get information (BASIC SKU is what we need) doing `fetchPlace()` but If I try to do like this:

```
val placeFields = asList(Place.Field.ID)
val fetchPlaceRequest = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(<CITY_NAME>, placeFields)
placesClient.fetchPlace(fetchPlaceRequest)
    .addOnSuccessListener { response ->
        <Do stuff with the place id retrieved>
     }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        <Do stuff in case of failure>
     }
```

But all the time falls in the Failure listener. I suppose I can't fetch the place using the city name instead of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about the sdk approach as i haven't used it, i have used the REST api apporach previously to do this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=&key=

Reducing cost will be tricky. Here's what i have resorted to in past projects to reduce this cost as best as i could:

1) the query will take place once every 2 characters are typed (you can change 2 to 3 or 4 or whatever is best for your project)

2) Save the results ie: place id and query in the local sqlite db. Before every actual autocomplete query, check if there is a matching result in the local db, if so, show those, else if no matching results are saved, then and only then perform the query.

A combination of these two should reduce your costs quite a bit as per my experience. Unfortunately i am only aware of these two solutions right now

Comment: used a Filterable inside a recyclerview adapter and called filter on change in the edittext